# animation.css and fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

how to do that?
I have this code for animation.css (http://justinaguilar.com/animations/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divAn = $('#an-container #forAnimation');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        divAn.each(function(){
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow+300) {
                var animation = $(this).attr('animate');
                if ( $(this).attr('animate') == null) animation = 'slideUp'; 
                $(this).addClass(animation);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

How to write correctly it using afterLoad in fullPage.js (https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks): 
`function (anchor Link, index) {....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fullpage.js option `scrollBar:true` of fullpage.js, that way the scroll event will get fired.